# How to properly setup mailgun in my laravel app?

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I am trying to setup mailgun in my laravel app but no matter what I try emails don't get sent.

My env file looks like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox....
MAILGUN_SECRET=key
```

No errors are thrown.

Best

Comment: Why don't you use MailTrap?

Comment: I want to setup mailgun to then switch easiely to production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The env should be like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mg.YOUR_DOMAIN.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

More information: https://www.mailgun.com/blog/build-laravel-5-7-email-authentication-mailgun-digital-ocean/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for testing (local dev) purposes I have to use the sandbox domain, right?